# aws service design and microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, microservices

I was curious about how AWS services are designed. For example, take a service like S3 and its REST API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html

There are *alot* of endpoints for this service, encompassing the full range of functionality of the 'S3 service'. However, behind the scenes, surely this is a collection of many microservices, at least that's what I'm thinking.

Anyone have any insight into this? A common design pattern you can point me to where a top-level service layer encapsulates individual calls to multiple microservices (if in fact, this is what they are doing)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical template for building such a storage service is based on a central request broker, that interacts with other services and dedicated databases:

- the storage broker handles REST requests from the users of the S3 API (but not only from the users, we will see it later),
- this broker makes use of other services to run:

  - the container or compute cloud services, for instance, are used by the broker to handle the service storage nodes or containers,
  - some database service (typically a nosql flexible database) is used to maintain the storage service databases,
  - the identity service that lets the broker validate the requests.
- this broker maintains some databases:

  - an object store database that maintains the long-term storage objects for users,
  - an account database with specific informations about the owners and access rights to objects stored in the object store,
  - a storage policy database that maintains service levels, features and behaviors depending on the users and object types.

The broker is offering services to the users, but also to some other services:

- the compute service may use the object storage service to maintain its configuration and states: the compute service sends REST requests to the storage service,
- the dashboard service may use the object storage service to maintain data collections,
- etc.

Looking further at some implementations of open source storage services, like the OpenStack Swift module, may help you find common design patterns that are used to implement such a service, based on other micro-services. For instance, you can look at section 1.2.2 of this guide: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_openstack_platform/10/pdf/architecture_guide/Red_Hat_OpenStack_Platform-10-Architecture_Guide-en-US.pdf

S3 is very similar to Swift since there are some gateways between the corresponding APIs.

Here is a diagram with such a pattern:

[image: object storage service pattern]